# Can message we are pushing to a Queue be moved to Active MQ Dead Letter Queue (DLQ) if any exception/connection error occur?

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms, jmstemplate

i am using Spring JmsTemplate for sending/pushing message to ActiveMQ queue.
i know after listener start processing that message and any exception occur,that message will be considered as a poison pill and moved to default DLQ of acive mq.

is that same possible (i.e. that message will move to default Dead Letter Queue ) while sending/pushing that message to Queue if there is any connection error or any other error occured while sending?

for example -

public void push(){

jmsTemplate.send(test.Queue, "This message is from client");
  //if any exception occur here,i want this message to be placed 
  in DLQ
}

please suggest is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't connect to send it the main queue, you probably can't connect to send it to the DLQ either.

Comment: i agree with what you said Gary. but consider a case where MQ Provider/server  is up n running  but someone has renamed the Queue @ provider but application client is still trying to connect to Queue with existing name. in this case is it possible to move message to DLQ ?

Comment: You can use Spring Retry to wrap the call to the template and when the retries are exhausted, try to send the message someplace else.

Comment: Yes we can use Spring Retry but this will move message to some other queue/place and we need to write that logic. but as i mentioned  while listening any  message is moved automatically to DLQ ,same i want to happen for push operation if its possible.

Comment: No; it's not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your help and suggestion Gary